# Images displaying incorrectly in IE8 and earlier

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css

For some reason images are being displayed as a thin line in IE 8 and earlier and i cannot work out why this could be. I'm using CSS to re-size the images for the homepage, the reason for me using CSS to re-size the images is because the thumnails are being generated by Wordpress.

This is what it looks like in IE...

[image: IE8 and below - thin images]

How it looks in Firefox and all other browsers...

[image: Firefox and other major browsers]

The CSS i'm using to size the images...

```
.home .attachment-home-post-thumbnail {
    box-shadow: none;
    height: 125px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    width: 140px;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add the markup for the images?

Comment: Inspect with your browser and tell us what CSS is actually being applied in ie8. Whatever the case, there's something in your css that firefox and other more modern browsers are picking up that ie8 doesn't understand. Obviously something to do with the width. That said, I've found that in many cases setting display:block takes care of a lot of weird quirks with older IEs.

Comment: The markup... <img width="200" height="112" alt="573667-copacabana-beach" class="attachment-home-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" src="/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/573667-copacabana-beach-200x112.jpg">